# Is a field extension of the form $\mathbb C[X, Y]/\mathfrak m$ isomorphic to $\mathbb C(k)$ for some algebraic $k$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak m}$
Let $\m$ be a maximal ideal of $\C[X, Y]$. We know that $\C[X, Y]/\m \simeq K$ will be a field (ring quotient maximal ideal is a field).

1. Is it true that we this field $K$ will always be *algebraic* over $\C$? That is, there exists some irreducible polynomial $p(t) \in \mathbb C[T]$ such that $\mathbb C[T]/(p) = \mathbb C[X, Y]/\mathfrak m$?
2. More generally, What happens over $\mathbb C[X_1, \dots, X_n]$?
3. Even more generally, over  any algebraically closed field $F$?
4. Even more broadly, is there a theory of "multivariate field extensions"? When I learnt finite field theory from Artin, we only considered the case of $F[X]/\mathfrak m$ for a field $F$, maximal ideal $\m$. What is the broader theory of $F[X_1, \dots X_n] / \mathfrak m$? Can we "reduce" this multi-variate case to the single variable case, something like how we reduce multilinear algebra to linear algebra by facotring through the tensor product?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353014/quotient-of-a-multivariable-polynomial-ring-by-a-maximal-ideal/3353066

Comment: The answer to (1)-(3) are usually the content of the first chapter of any book of algebraic geometry. Look for Hilbert's nullstellensatz and related discussion.

Comment: I hope you know that all irreducible polynomials over complex numbers are linear.

Comment: @Mohan indeed. Not sure how that helps in the multivariate case?

Comment: @Gae.S. I was asking this in order to gain an intuition for the nullstellensatz :( So does this "inexoriably" lead to the nullstellensatz?

Comment: Some issues of yours are more fundamental: for instance, in (1) you seem to believe that $\Bbb C$ might have algebraic field extensions, much like $\Bbb Q$ has $\Bbb Q\left[\sqrt2\right]$, but that is of course not the case because $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed, and therefore it's its own algebraic closure. (2) and (3) you are asking what happens with maximal ideals in the polynomial rings $\Bbb C[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ and $k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]$ with $k=\overline k$, therefore I don't know what answer you expect, if not a theorem (nullstellensatz) describing the maximal ideals of those rings.